# Where does the error occur when I store the pointer to a array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct record
{
    char*title;
    char* year;
    char* length; //in minutes
} record;

void read(record* list[]);
void test(record* list[]);

int main(int args, char* argv[])
{
  record* list[1024];
  read(list); //add record to list (pass by reference)

  test(list);

  write(list);


  return 0;
}
void test(record* list[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<1024; ++i)
    {
        if(list[i]!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%s index %d \n", list[i]->title ,i);
        }
    }
}

void read(record* list[])
{
    int j;  //ini a array of pointer initially point to null
    for(j=0;j<1024;++j)
      list[j]=NULL;

   FILE* input=fopen("input.txt","r"); //file in
   if(!input)
   {
        printf("Error"); exit(1);
   }else
   {
       int i=0; //index for adding elements to array
       char temp[100];
       while(!feof(input))
       {
           record* current_record=(record*)malloc(sizeof(record));

           fgets(temp,sizeof(temp),input);  //temp is a line of file
           char deli[]=" ";

           char* result=NULL;
           result=strtok(temp,deli);  //titile info
           current_record->title=result;

           result=strtok(NULL,deli); //year
           current_record->year=result;

           result=strtok(NULL,deli); //length
           current_record->length=result;

           list[i]=current_record; //add to array
           printf("%s \n",current_record->title);
           ++i;
       }
       fclose(input);
   }
}
```

This is what my program does:
1. read a file line by line
2. store all the info in a line to a struct and store all the structs to a array. This array is a array of pointers. When elements unused, the pointer points to null.
3. test method. I want to print the data in a struct in this array.

Test method printed a weird output. Could anyone help me what the problem is? Dont tell me how to fix. Thank you.

input.txt:

```
zombieland 2009 88

avatar 2009 178

watchmen 2009 215
```

Comment: That weird output is probably memory addresses. Also why `record* list[1024]`?

Comment: This isn't really your problem, but it would speed up your program if you did: `if(list[i] == NULL) break;` and then the printf statement on the next line.

Comment: OT: It's not a good idea to use the names of system calls (here: `read()`) for you rown functions, at least if not by special intention.

Comment: OT^2: `null` is differnet form `NULL`.

Comment: "*Dont tell me how to fix.*" Err .. what else?

Comment: +1 for a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You error is that you don't keep copies of data read from the file.

When you read data you put that data into local variable `temp`. Then you set various pointers to different places in `temp` (you should **copy** to different memory). When you read another line, you override the contents of `temp` but the pointers still point to the same place

```
step 1 read zombieland 2009 88
pointers    ^          ^    ^

step 2 read avatar 2009 178
oldpointers ^          ^    ^
newpointers ^      ^    ^
```

In short: copy the result of `strtok()` to a brand new `malloc`'d memory.

Oh! And don't forget to `free()` the memory when you no longer need it (probably at the end of the program).

Comment: Thank you so much. I should copy the content instead of just making the pointer pointing to it.

Comment: Right! You could make your struct members be char arrays and could avoid `malloc`ing memory at every step; but either way works as long as you **copy**.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(tmp) + 1))` is definitely safer.

Comment: ... or just use `strdup()`, if available. @ciphermagi